# How to get a float value into a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

Im trying to find the correct way to  get a float value into a `UIAlertView`. My `float` value  is only used to check another value rather than passed to string somewhere.

I suppose I could set my `float` value to a label and set it to `hidden` and pass that to my alert, but im sure this cant be the proper way to do this, some advice would be appreciated

```
float x = ([_continuityRingFinalR1.text floatValue]); /stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", x * y]]
float y = (1.67);

if ([_continuityRingFinalRn.text floatValue] > x * y ) {


         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Advisory Warning"
         message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Based on your value of %@  this value may not be acceptable. %@ would be acceptable",_continuityRingFinalR1.text, ]///<<< my float value here
         delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ignore" otherButtonTitles: @"Retest", nil];



    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**%f** is used in an NSString for a float/double instead of %@

```
    float x = ([_continuityRingFinalR1.text floatValue]); /stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", x * y]]
    float y = (1.67);
    float example;

    if ([_continuityRingFinalRn.text floatValue] > x * y ) {

             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Advisory Warning"
             message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Based on your value of %@  this value may not be acceptable. %f would be acceptable",_continuityRingFinalR1.text, example];
             delegate:self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ignore" otherButtonTitles: @"Retest", nil];

        [alert show];
    }
```

Here's a helpful [link](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/NSLog)

Comment: thats it thanks, id tried something similar but xcode kept autocorrecting my %f to %%f causing the issue, thanks for tip. Plus one for you

Comment: Wierd... Xcode should NOT be behaving like that :P

Comment: When it auto fixed %@ it kept the first % so making it %%f that threw me! thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this

```
message:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Based on your value of %@  this value may not be acceptable. %0.2f would be acceptable",_continuityRingFinalR1.text, x*y ];
//Passing second argument as x*y
```